# Non-Latin characters in html input fields

Tags: html, character-encoding, html-input, non-latin

I am having an issue with non-Latin characters. For example, if I go to the link below and type in "ü" and press submit, İ get %C3%BC instead of that letter. I have tried to use `content="text/html; charset=utf-8 "`, but it did not work. Do you guys have any idea how I can avoid the issue?

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_form_submit

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't really avoid the issue; decoding of such characters needs to happen server-side.  In PHP the [urldecode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php) function is used for this, so urldecode('%C3%BC') returns 'ü'.  This behaviour is part of [the way that forms work](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#form-content-type) - if you look at the code for the Stack Overflow form that I'm using to submit this answer:

```
<form id="post-form" action="/questions/37262431/answer/submit" method="post" class="post-form">
```

I'm able to use the letter ü, but the form doesn't contain any extra attributes, because the server is decoding the '%C3%BC' before returning 'ü' to the client.

Comment: thanks, I had that in my mind, wanted to check if there was a better option.